# How to embed an external library in node_modules with script tag into react component?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, vite

I'd like to embed an external library I installed in the node_modules into my react component via script tag and I wonder how to do it

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    // script.src = `node_modules/${libraryPath}` 
    containerRef.current?.append(script)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason I try this approach is that the library doesn't export anything and it's designed to be executed itself so I haven't got to come up with any other way to use it.

p.s. I'm using Vite as build tool

Comment: If it is in your `node_modules` directory I believe you can just import it, e.g. `import "whateverLibraryName";`.

Comment: @DrewReese I need to add the library through script tag within the div element. That's how the library is made to work unfortunately

Comment: What is this node module? Can you [edit] to add more details and possibly a more complete [mcve]?